# What determines Charge Controller PV input limits?

Tags: battery-charging, solar-cell

What determines how much PV wattage a charge controller can accept?

For instance - I am looking at a 50 amp charge controller with a max input voltage of 150v.

In the specs it lists max PV input as 750W for 12v and 1500W for 24V. This would put the input around 60A.

In this particular PV array I'm working on, I have 1000W - 68v at 15a coming off the roof. According to the CC input limits (150V,~60A) it should be able to accommodate that much PV. But the specs list a much lower PV input limit.

What am I missing? How can I properly size a charge controller?

Answer (score 3):

What you're missing is the fact that the input specification is telling you how much power the charge controller needs from the PV array. It is not a limit that you must enforce. On the contrary, it means that your array needs to be able to supply at least that much power in order to max out the charger.

The charge controller is designed to deliver up to 50 A to either a 12-volt or a 24-volt battery pack. At 12 volts (nominal), that represents an output power of 13.7 V × 50 A = 685 W. Since they're telling you that it requires 750 W of input power, you can infer that the charger's overall conversion efficiency is about 685 W / 750 W = 91.3 %.

If your PV array voltage is 68 V, then you need to be able to deliver 750 W / 68 V = 11 A to the charger in order to run it at its full capacity. Since your array can actually deliver 15 A, you will not be able to use the full output of your array. In other words, your array has excess capacity relative to what the charger can actually use.

On the other hand, if your battery pack is 24 V, then the charger needs 1500 W, and your array would have to deliver 22 A to run it at full capacity. Since your array can only deliver 15 A, the charger will charge the battery at a maximum of about

$$ \frac{15 A \cdot 68 V}{27.4 V} \cdot 91\% = 34 A$$

This is fine; it just means that your charger has some excess capacity relative to your PV array.